# Find the max number of child nodes in tree

Tags: java, tree

I am trying to create a method which would return the biggest number of children (child nodes) that any node has. However, my code is incorrectly reading deepers levels.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private List<Person> children = new ArrayList<Person>();

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void addChild(Person child) {
    children.add(child);
}

public int returnMaxChildren() {
    int count = children.size();
    for (Person child : children)
        if (child.children.size() > count)
            count = child.children.size();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: @MS90 Like I said, find out which node has the most child nodes and then return the number of child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code takes amount of children of current node, and then compares it with amount of grandchildren (children of current children). But that is it.

If you want to get max amount of children of any descendent node you may want to let children calculate their *max* same way, by recursively calling `returnMaxChildren` on them.

```
public int returnMaxChildren() {
    int count = children.size();
    for (Person child : children){
        int childMax = child.returnMaxChildren();
        if (childMax > count){
            count = childMax;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a method to count all children:

```
public int countChildren() {
    int retVal = children.size();
    for (Person child : children) {
        retVal += child.countChildren();
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

With that, you can look in your object for the child with the most nodes:

```
public int returnMaxChildren() {
    int retVal = 0;
    for (Person child : children) {
        if (child.countChildren() > retVal) {
            retVal = child.countChildren();
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: your code is not working. It's count all children from level 2 and more, not finding the person with most children.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood your question. So you want more or less know which node has the highest count of its own children? ```public int returnMaxChildren() {
  int retVal = children.size();
  for (Person child : children) {
   if (child.returnMaxChildren() > retVal) {
    retVal = child.returnMaxChildren();
   }
  }
  return retVal;
 }``` This goes again recursively through all nodes and looks which node has the highest children count. I hope this works better.